# Using PHPUnit with PHP-DI

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, phpunit, php-di

I'm using the PHP-DI library and it works great for my code by [using a bootstrap and config file](https://github.com/PHP-DI/demo/tree/master/app), as recommended by the PHP-DI documentation.

Then, in my app, I'm getting the container and kicking things off by calling the bootstrap:

```
$container = require __DIR__ . '/Container/bootstrap.php';
$main = $container->get( Main::class );
```

So now I'm trying to set up unit testing with PHPUnit.

I'd like to get ahold of the $container in each Test class so that I can inject all of the dependencies of each test by using $container->injectOn($this) [as suggested in the PHP-DI documentation](http://php-di.org/doc/inject-on-instance.html#why).

I stumbled on this open issue [which is mostly over my head], but it is still open and doesn't seem to have any recommendations.

https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/issues/125

My only thoughts are that I could just call bootstrap in setUp() the same way as my main app?

```
$container = require __DIR__ . '/Container/bootstrap.php';
```

Is this what I should be doing? Is there a more elegant or recommended way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: _Side note:_ PHP-DI isn't a framework. It's a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes bootstrapping your container in your test is perfectly OK. If your bootstrap is doing too many things that might get more complicated, but ideally your bootstrap shouldn't do much (just configure the container and create the application class).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback -- I did not mention in my original query, this is for a Wordpress plugin, and I'm using the Wordpress plugin testing tools, which loads WP, which loads my plugin, which boots the container, etc... Is it a problem that the WP loader is booting it, as well as my test code? Edit: It seems to be working to test fine... I was just wondering if I should continue to investigate a way to simplify so that the container is loaded only once.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure but as long as it works and it isn't too slow, rebooting as much as possible between tests is never a bad thing. At least every test is isolated from the others.